# Mongoose, upsert an item in array in referenced subdocument

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, upsert

I have the following schemas and models:

```
const shelfSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        default: 'New Shelf'
    },
    books: {
        type: [bookSchema],
        required: false
    }
}, {autoCreate: false})

const shelfModel = mongoose.model('Shelf', shelfSchema)
```

```
const librarySchema= new mongoose.Schema({
    shelves: {
        type: [shelfSchema],
        required: false,
    }
})

const libraryModel = mongoose.model('library', librarySchema)
```

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required:true,
        unique:true
    }
    library: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'library',
        required: true
    }
})
const userModel = mongoose.model('User', userSchema );
```

Every User has a unique username and a Library reference, and every library has one or more Shelves, each one with one or more Book.

When I add a book, I pass also the information of the shelf name I want to insert the book into, and if the shelf with that name is missing, it should be created.

Since I come from a sql mentality I'm having a bit of difficulties in understanding if I can manage an upsert the same way.

I thought that I could insert the book using at most two queries: one to create the self if it's missing and one to insert the book in the shelf.

My approach was then to use

```
UserModel.findOneAndUpdate({username: user.username, "library.shelves.name": shelfName},{}, {upsert: true})
```

but since it's a query in the UserModel, if it doesn't find a user with a shelf with that name it tries to create a new user, duplicating the username.
Am I right to assume that I have to split this first query in two parts, "Find a user with a shelf with that name in the library" and in case it's not found "Create that shelf in the library"?
Or is it possible to unite the queries in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing right now is trying to update a `UserModel` that matches the user name, has the shelve name, that is why `upsert: true` creates a new user entry.

What you should do is to find out the library `_id` and then [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) the book to the shelf you are searching for.

Comment: So, I need a separate query only to fetch the library's _id ?

Comment: Yep and then update the library.

Comment: In case the shelf model had a reference to its library, I would have a different situation right? In that case I could just work with a simple upsert